# Selenium-Webdriver JAVA:- i am getting error ""org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element""" but Appointment Icon is present

Tags: dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify the tool tip but getting error no such element. I have confirmed that element is exist.

Java Code:

```
String toolTipTextAppointment = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .id("//*[@id='EditView_NOTE_POPUP']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(toolTipTextAppointment);
```

HTML Code:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="border:0px;">
<a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showPopupActivity('Meetings','activityPopupFormAraContent',440,600);">
<img style="border: 6px none;" title="Appointment" src="themes/AutoAccelerator/images/calender_icon.gif"/>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: HTML code:
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="border:0px;">
<a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showPopupActivity('Meetings','activityPopupFormAraContent',440,600);">
<img style="border: 6px none;" title="Appointment" src="themes/AutoAccelerator/images/calender_icon.gif"/>
</a>
</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='calender_icon.gif']")).getAttribute("title")
```

Answer (score 1):

**you have used findElement(By.id("")) but you passed xpath in it that is why it is not working**

String toolTipTextAppointment = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/a/img")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(toolTipTextAppointment);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is visibility. There are two different concepts, existence and visibility (reachable to click or see).

You need to check if the element is visible, not sure about the syntax as I use the clojure library (clj-webdriver) but as far as I know should be shomething like this

```
e=driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed();
```

Take into account that the driver will find hidden element but they are not visible. In this particular case you may need to scroll down the page to make the element visible, I suggest retrieve its  `e.location` and use the coordinates with a javascript snippet

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + e.location +  ")");`

Then the element will be visible and you will be able to interact with it, I usually have this code embedded in a helper function as it's a quite common issue.

Disclaimer: code is just an orientation, I don't know the syntax as I don't use Java. Hope it helps